# Session clears ends when debugging ASP.NET but works fine on the dev and test server

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I'm having a strange issue where the session ends after a postback when I debug it in visual studio 2010.

I store a variable in a session on the first page. It keeps its value in the next page but after that it gets lost. It returns a null value. The strange thing is when i copy the exact code to the dev or test servers, it works fine...

Any ideas what could be happening? Thanks.

**UPDATE**
The code is fairly simple. I have a **default.aspx** page where I'm setting a session variable:

```
 HttpContext.Current.Session["PurchaseOID"] = purchaseOID;
```

When I click 'Next' the Default.aspx page redirects it to a Information.aspx page. Additional user information is gathered on this page (using DevExpress controls). When I click 'Next' on this page the session variable "PurhcaseOID" returns null on page load.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      if(HttpContext.Current.Session["PurchaseOID"] == null){
        throw new Exception("error!");
      }
}
```

Whats strange is, the Session is kept when the page is first loaded. But on postback, it loses its variables. Also, this is something that JUST started happening. I've been working on this code for a month or so and it's been working fine. When I deploy this exact code to our dev or test server, it works fine.

I'm debugging this in Cassini. Help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Shahzad Chaudhary

Comment: Posting code would be helpful.

Comment: @Dan Would like to second this.  My answer below is really an extreme shot in the dark based on a similar wtf moment I had.

Comment: Are you debugging on IIS or cassini?

Comment: Are you editing code between page views at all? Also can you post some code.

Comment: Sorry, I'll add code as soon as I get a chance.

Comment: Please post your session state config from your web.config.  Are you using InProc sessions, a session state server, SQL server?

Comment: Are your default.aspx and Information.aspx pages within the same project?  I'm just thinking that perhaps your dev and test servers are configured for session to be shared between two applications, whereas in your local dev environment it's not.  If both pages are in the same project, though, then this probably isn't your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, it was a stupid mistake. The change was happening in the Global.asax Application_Error method. For some reason when I put a breakpoint there it wouldn't hit.

Answer (score 1):

When you are testing do you have cookies disabled?  I ask because the session id is stored in a cookie unless you are using cookieless sessions (rare).  So if in your test environment you have cookies turned off in your browser then it will not be able to get the session values.  I don't believe it throws any error when storing them though.

Comment: I just wanted to make it clear that nobody in the world would ever be silly enough to set <httpCookies requireSSL="true" /> in their web.config and then attempt to debug over plain http.

Answer (score 0):

When local debug, just set in web.config

```
<sessionState cookieless="true" />
```